# powering raspberry pi zeroW via computer usb port

Tags: power-supply, pi-zero-w, usb-power

I ran out of wall plugs for the Pi and I would like to power a zeroW via a USB port from my laptop.  There are 2 microusb ports on the zeroW should which 1 should I use, the one near the edge or the one near the middle?  Also is this viable?  T

Comment: read the labels on the board

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a Zero W from any USB2.0 500mA supply. You can't run any USB peripherals in that configuration (it needs about 750mA as soon as you plug in any USB device).

The middle connector is USB. The connector near the corner is the power (although you can power from either connector as the +VE and -VE connections are linked).